# Need help figuring out Functional Dependencies

Tags: functional-dependencies

I have a problem where they ask me to get functional dependencies but I'm not entirely sure if I got them correctly, this topic seems a bit confusing, I was wondering if you guys could double check for me or correct me if I'm wrong please!

```
Company(companyID, companyName, cityName, country, assets)
Department(deptID, deptName, companyID, cityName, country, deptMgrID)
City(cityID, cityName, country)

-Two different companies cannot have the same company ID
-Two different departments cannot have the same deptID
-Two different cities cannot have the same cityID
-Two different cities in the same country cannot have the same name.
-The company name and the city it’s located in determine the company ID.
-Two departments in the same company must have different names.
-One manager cannot run two different departments.
```

These are the FDs I came up with:

```
companyID -> companyName,cityName,country,assets
deptID -> deptName,companyID,cityName,country,deptMgrID
cityID -> cityName,country
country,cityID -> cityName
companyName,cityName -> companyID
deptID -> deptMgrID
deptID,country -> deptName
```

Answer (score 0):

> Two different companies cannot have the same company ID

I'd interpret that to mean that Company.companyID is unique. *That* means

- companyID -> Company.companyName
- companyID -> Company.cityName
- companyID -> Company.country
- companyID -> Company.assets

> Two different departments cannot have the same deptID

Same interpretation as above. The FDs should be obvious.

> Two different cities cannot have the same cityID

Same interpretation. Again, the FDs should be obvious.

> Two different cities in the same country cannot have the same name.

I'd interpret that to mean that {city name, country name} is unique. That means it's a candidate key, and *that* means that every FD that has cityID on the left hand side can be repeated with {city name, country name} on the left hand side.

> The company name and the city it’s located in determine the company ID.

- companyName, cityName, country -> companyID

> Two departments in the same company must have different names.

I'd interpret that to mean that the department name is not unique, but {companyID, deptName} *is*. That makes {companyID, deptName} a candidate key. So every FD that has Department.deptID on the left hand side can be repeated with {companyID, deptName} on the left hand side.

> One manager cannot run two different departments.

deptMgrID is a candidate key. See above.